# Not able to run newman collection with docker by using steps provided in the documentation of newman docker run

Tags: docker, postman, ubuntu-18.04, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am having very basic knowledge with ubuntu(linux) os and have just started with dockers.

Now I have to create a postman/newman docker which is having a volume(or any other storage type) containing postman collection jsons, environment jsons and data jsons.

I have tried to google and understand and also gone through the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/develop/docker/).

I have already setup the docker for ubuntu(linux).

Now I have created a directory with name "Newman Docker" on "/home/user" path.

Afterwards I have created a directory with name "collections" having collection and environment files inside the "Newman Docker" directory.

Now via terminal I have navigated upto "Newman Docker" directory.

Afterwards I have used `docker pull postman/newman:ubuntu` command.

Now when trying to run below command, but it is not working:

```
docker run -v ~/collections:/etc/newman -t postman/newman:ubuntu \
    run "xyz.postman_collection.json" \
    --environment="abc.postman_environment.json" \
    --reporters="json,cli" --reporter-json-export="newman-results.json"
```

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: @YaronIdan I was getting "enoent no such file" error which is solved now.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting "enoent no such file" error which is solved now.

First I renamed the directory "Newman Docker" to "newmanDocker" for ease of using commands.

And then I had not given path from root directory which I have provided now, below is the updated command for the same:

```
docker run -v ~newmanDocker/collections:/etc/newman -t postman/newman:ubuntu \
    run "xyz.postman_collection.json" \
    --environment="abc.postman_environment.json" \
    --reporters="json,cli" --reporter-json-export="newman-results.json"
```

Comment: If any moderator is seeing this, please close this question as it has been solved.